# Быстрый парс сайта | Kotlin | Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, парсер, kotlin, jsoup, okhttp

Подскажите, как быстрее парсить сайт? Раньше использовал Jsoup, но заметил, что перед выводом данных проходит около 1с, что заметно долго. Поэтому возник вопрос, быстрее ли парсит OkHTTP? И, если нет, то как получить прирост к скорости?

Comment: Главный вопрос: Время тратится на парсинг, или на получение информации из сети? А то, может, и не в парсере проблема?)

Comment: Не уверен. Как проверить? Где посмотреть статистику?

Comment: Сохраните страницу локально в файл, прочтите в строку, после чего - распарсите. Замерьте время, которой уходит на этот парсинг (без учета обращения к сети и проч) и Вы узнаете, сколько времени уходит на парсинг, все остальное - доступ к сети

Comment: Замерил данные. На подключение к ресурсу (Jsoup.connect(URL).get()) уходит чуть более 1 секунды и примерно столько же на обработку данных.